# Yii CGridView pagination и редактирование записей

Tags: cgridview, paging, yii, ajax

Добрый день!

В админке вывожу таблицу со списком записей, для вывода использую CGridView.
Допустим, нахожусь на 5-й странице, перехожу на редактирование записи на этой странице, необходимо, чтобы после сохранения выполнился редирект на 5ю страницу. Пагинация работает через Ajax. Подскажите, как можно реализовать это.

Вот сам грид:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView',array(
   'id' => 'content-list',
   'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
   'enablePagination' => true,
   'filter'=>$model,
   'columns' => array(
        'id',
        'title',
        'category',
         array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'template' => '{comments}{update}{delete}',
            'updateButtonUrl' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("admin/content/manage",  array("id"=>$data->id))',
            'deleteButtonUrl' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("admin/content/delete", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                'buttons' => array(
                    'comments' => array(
                        'label' => 'Комментарии',
                        'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("admin/content/comments",array("id"=>$data->id))',                                                                                            'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true).'/images/comment_edit.png',
                    ),
                )
        )
    ),
)),
```

Comment: А как вы реализовывали пагинацию через аякс?

Comment: в своем экшне проверяете откуда пришел запрос, если это ajax, то рендерите шаблон без layout в переменную, и отправляете обратно скрипту. А в скрипте уже смотрите на ответ, и куда вставлять html с ответа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну как показывает практика..

Если мы смотрим все на странице

controller/admin/ и там у нас грид

то ссылки будут вида

```
controller/admin/controller_page/2
controller/admin/controller_page/3
controller/admin/controller_page/4
controller/admin/controller_page/5
```

Собственно, когда ты обновляешь запись сделай редирект на нужную страницу, ну а как получить этот id страницы думаю не сложно догадаться, что через referrer :)

```
$page=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; // его разбираем на части и нужную достаем

$this->redirect(array('admin','controller_page'=>$page)); // примерно так.
```

единственное что подставляй нужный контроллер перед **_page** и все счастье будет :)

Comment: а в случаей с ajax пагинацией и ajax валидацией при сохранении как быть? в $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] нету номера страницы. Проблема только номер получить. Может как то можно в updateBtn в параметры передать номер? что не пойму как)

Comment: Ну там же все передается GET массивом, подставь к иконкам новый параметр


    'updateButtonUrl' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("admin/content/manage",  array("id"=>$data->id,"page"=>,$_GET['controller_page']))',

Comment: Супер, спасибо. Вот мой код, может кому-то пригодится:

во view:

    'updateButtonUrl' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("admin/pages/manage", array("id"=>$data->id,"page"=>isset($_GET["Page_page"]) ? $_GET["Page_page"] : 1))',

в контроллере:

    $this->redirect(array('pages/index/','Page_page'=>Yii::app()->request->getParam('page',1)));

Comment: Круть что помог, удачи. Yii простой фреймворк. Главное просто иногда не сильно париться и решать задачи на простом подходе :)

Comment: Да, действительно, тут проще некуда, спасибо. )